# How to Add the Split App into Main Full Screen app in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I am working on a Master Detail application in SAPUI5. I have created the master view containing the list of information. On top of the master section I have placed one button to view the hierarchy information about the list in Full screen.

So my question is how to switch the view from Master-Detail (Split App) to Full Screen.

Comment: Do you want to hide your master, so that the Detail Page has the hole screen? I don't get it

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using a SplitApp directly, you could use an App with a SplitContainer so you have a structure like this:

```
- App
  - FullScreenView
  - SplitContainer
    - MasterView
    - DetailView
```

See a minimal example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/gD8bJk

Comment: Thank you so much. But in my application i am not using router functionality.I have a root view called App.view.js and App.controller.js. As you suggested i made the changes on App.view.js. Now sap.m.App is my parent view type. But now i need to add the Full screen view and Split app view with my Main view. How to achieve this?

Comment: Use the Router. Is there any reason not to use it?  

Generally you could also copy the behavior by setting the content of the App and SplitContainer in the Controller, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: There is no any specific reason for that. i  will try it out. Thanks

Comment: @hirse: Your Plunker is VERY enlightening and solved this problem for me. Thanks!

Comment: A notice for a SplitApp component: As of SAPUI5 release 1.48, the split screen layout is deprecated for freestyle applications. https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/split-screen/

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem, using a SplitApp in a App.
The App needs to be filled with pages, not with a SplitApp. You probably can create a page, set the SplitApp as her content and add it to the App. But believe me, it doesn't look good.

The only solution you have is to disable the App and enable the SplitApp. 
I'm doing this with two div-containers:

```
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content" onload="init()">
     <div id="content_app"></div>
     <div id="content_splitapp"></div>
</body>
```

and control the display elemnt if I want to show the SplitApp:

```
document.getElementById('content_app').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('content_splitapp').style.display = 'inline';
splitApp.placeAt("content_splitapp");
```

or if I want to go back to the App:

```
document.getElementById('content_splitapp').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('content_app').style.display = 'block';
```

Hope this helps you